# Is there any way to retrieve the query metadata in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there any way to retrieve the column metadata from a query (something like what DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable() does)? I'm basically looking for things like a columns length if it's a string, or if it's a numeric field its precision/scale. This info seems to be lost as it gets projected into a class.

I know you can query the static table metadata, but that doesn't really help me. I also know I can get the DbDataReader if I run an explicit SQL query instead of using LINQ. But I really don't want to do that in this case.

I've been digging through the EF 6 source code and it doesn't look like it exposes this metadata anywhere - but there is a lot going on so it's possible I missed it or didn't think of some way of getting to it.

Any ideas?